# How to create a property, in owner, from python level

Tags: python, game-engine, properties

**Hello there.**

I am creating a game in UpBGE, and I am often use python to it.

A moment ago I encountered a problem:

I do not really know, how to create a property, in owner, from python level.

[image]

Thank you for any helpful comments.

Comment: What do you mean with 'from Python level'? A global property? If so, how could it be attached to owner? Object properties (owner) can be set like owner["prop"] = value, global properties can be set using bge.logic.globalDict["prop"] = value, but the last aren't attached to any object. If it's not what you mean, explain a little better your question.